# Can't call jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my code.
I want to call a function but it's not working.

First, function show() displays button. This button has id='send' and it's inside the div with class='messagebox'. I want to call function on button click.
(I call function show in php script)

```
echo<<<ENDL 

<div class="friendslistimgbox" onclick="show('$id','$login','$photo')">....</div>

ENDL;
```

$(.messagebox #send) or $(.messagebox > #send) are not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
    conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
    };

    conn.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log(e.data);
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var row = data.from+": "+data.msg+"<br/>";

        $("#chats").append(row);
    };

    $(".messagebox #send").click(function(){
        var userId = $("#userId").val();
        var msg = $("#msg").val();
        var data = {
            userId: userId,
            msg: msg
        };
        conn.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    })
})

function show(id,login,photo){      
    $('.messagebox').html("<input type='hidden' id='userId' value='"+login+"'><input type='text' id='msg' class='sendmessage'><button id='send' type='submit' class='button_sendmessage'><i class='icon-right-dir'></i></button>");
    $('#message_to').html("<a href='"+login+"'><img src='../userphotos/"+photo+"'>"+login+"</a>");
    $("#allmessagesbox").css("visibility","visible");
}
```

HTML /

```
<div class="allmessagesbox" id="allmessagesbox">
    <div class="messages">
        <div class="message_to" id="message_to"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="messagebox"></div>
</div>
<div id="chats"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a `console.log` at the beginning of your `click` handler to make sure it isn't being called?

Comment: When is `show` executed? I suspect you are trying to specify the `click` handler before the button element exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the `.on()` method to register events with DOM elements that are dynamic (ie like your button, which might exist in the future).

In the case of your code, you can use `on()` in the following way:

```
// Replace this line:
// $(".messagebox #send").click(function(){
// With this:
$("body").on("click", ".messagebox #send", function(){

    var userId = $("#userId").val();
    var msg = $("#msg").val();
    var data = {
        userId: userId,
        msg: msg
    };
    conn.send(JSON.stringify(data));
})
```

This can basically be read and understood as:

```
// For any dynamic element in scope or child of the body
$("body")
// Register a click event with any element that matches the
// .messagebox #send selector either now, or in the future
.on("click", ".messagebox #send", function(){

...

}));
```

For more information on `on()`, see the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/)